# Overiding function with specific type in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, types, parameters

I'm trying to override a function when a specific type is passed as a parameter.

```
def __getitem__(self, x: str):
    ...
```

This works in Python 3 but not 2. Is there an equivalent in Python 2 or some way of achieving the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 does not have type hinting. You can just not give the type hint, and handle the body of the function however you like.

```
def __getitem__(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return self.data[x]
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        return self.numbers[x]
    else:
        return 0
```